# Not able to run DBF file in Rstudio

Tags: r, dbf

```
library(foreign)
data <- read.dbf("C:\\Users\\xx\\\abc.dbf")
```

Used above command to run a dbf file in Rstudio but it shows below error:
unable to open DBF file

Have already installed Foreign and Maptool packages.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please check the path is correct.